# simple R 3d interpolation / surface plot using pycnophylactic interpolation

Tags: r, 3d, interpolation, surface

I would like to create a 3d surface from a set of points (x,y,z) like this scenario [simple R 3d interpolation/surface plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508059/simple-r-3d-interpolation-surface-plot) but using a specific interpolation method called pycnophylactic. There's a package called pycno with this method but I'm new in R and can't understand well how can I do it. Can anyone help me, provide a sample? My data is something like this:

```
x <- c(-19.915909,-19.918794,-19.914678,-1.991492,-19.916232)
y <- c(-43.942983,-43.943198,-43.940344,-43.942168,-43.939507)
z <- c(7.910,5.693,6.958,7.116,790.843)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I used the "akima" package to interpolate the z variable. Here's how the 3D plot would look for your x, y and z.

```
dens <- akima::interp(x,y,z, duplicate = "mean")
plot_ly(x=dens$x,y=dens$y,z=dens$z) %>% add_surface()
```

[image]